# pre-start mongodb with node js

Tags: mongodb

I am getting issue in starting mongodb with npm prestart , I have windows pc and I want to run node project and mongodb should with node project, please tell me what is doing wrong.

```
 "scripts": {
"prestart": "start mongod --config ./mongod.cfg",
"start": "node ./dist/server/",
"poststart": "start mongo stoneGym --eval 
 \"db.getSiblingDB('stoneGym').shutdownServer()\""
```

},

Comment: Why do you only want to run mongodb whilst your dist server is running??. Surely you can just run as a service and simply not have the issue. You are aware you can actually run as a service? Because the problem here is the `mongod` is simply not going to "hang up" since it's being launched interactively. Since it therefore does not "complete" then I guess it just blocks everything else. If you need to be told then then you're just learning things. And if you are learning, then you should simply run as a service and worry about such things when you understand them better.